# AngularJS "Argument 'mainController' is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im new to Angular and need some help.

I'm trying to setup a basic directory structure where i have modules and controllers in seperate JS-files. However, when i do this i get the error stated in the posts title.

The module looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Controllers like this:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
$scope.message = 'Test message';
});
```

And routes:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

// route for the home page
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

// route for the about page
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'components/about/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
})

// route for the contact page
.when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: 'components/contact/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactController'
});
});
```

Then in my HTML i use ng-app="myApp" and ng-controller="mainController" and trying to write out: {{message}} from it. But it doesn't work.

If i put all the angular code in the same JS-file, then it works. But not when they are seperated.

Help and an explaination is highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you include all the files once you separated them?

Comment: My guess is you have not included the module.js, controller.js and routes.js in your index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, this error is usually caused my a missing reference to the file that contains your mainController. Your index.html should contain script references to your javascript files. Here is an example from one of my small apps:

```
<!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="/login/loginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/home/homeCtrl.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="/common/directives/pageHeader/pageHeader.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="/common/directives/footerGeneric/footerGeneric.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="/common/directives/queryBuilder/queryBuilder.directive.js"></script>
    <script src="/common/directives/scroll/infScroll.js"></script>
```

All of this should come after including jquery and angular. Additionally (I don't know where you include app.js successfully, you may have already done this) you need to direct AngularJS routes to the index.html file from your express server (assuming express/node backend) in your main app file like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));
app.use(function (req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client', 'index.html'))
});
```

I hope this was helpful. If you post the code where you attempt to include your application and controller then I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Seems like i had forgot the controller script.. Wow, that's sloppy! Ah well, thank you!